# Laravel - How to a try/catch in blade view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I would like to create a way to compile in a view, the try/catch.
How can I do this in Laravel?

Example:

```
@try
<div class="laravel test">
    {{ $user->name }}
</div>
@catch(Exception $e)
    {{ $e->getMessage() }}
@endtry
```

Comment: You shouldn't be try/catching in the view. That should happen in the controller.

Comment: I know it's not a good idea. But I'm curious to "creating a keyword to compile this"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should *not* have `try`/`catch` blocks in your view. A view is exactly that: a representation of some data. That means you should not be doing any logic (such as exception handling). That belongs in the controller, once you’ve fetched data from model(s).

If you’re just wanting to display a default value in case a variable is undefined, you can use a standard [PHP null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) to display a default value:

```php
{{ $user->name ?? 'Name not set' }}
```

Comment: I'm having a problem when calling `{{ url()->previous() }}` function in the exception blade. I don't have a controller to handle the data. The `try` block would help me big time. Sometimes it is better to give an answer and not an advice.

Answer (score 18):

You are probably doing something wrong if you need a `try..catch` in your view. But that does not mean you should never do it. There are exceptions to every rule.

So anyway, here is the answer:

Put raw PHP in your view by using `<?php ?>` or `@php @endphp` tags. Then put your `try..catch` in the raw PHP.

```
@php
    try {
        // Try something
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Do something exceptional
    }
@endphp
```

Answer (score 5):

while i agree with @areed that something is wrong if you have to use a try...catch, there are weird cases where a wrong approach can lead you down that path. One instance is using the same blade to house a `paginate()` and a `get()` response. Well, this might help a little.

```
<?php try{ ?> 
    //try to show something
    {{ $products->links() }}
<?php }catch(\Exception $e){ ?>
    // show something else
<?php } ?>
```